# JS Array Loop Number is 1 Off

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops

I'm importing json data and looping through divs to supply them with object values. The divs in my array begin with a number but the first number is 0. I understand why this is, but how do I fix this to start the first div with 1 and not 0?

Thanks

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Brackets.json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {

    var items = [ "#bracket1", "#bracket2", "#bracket3", "#bracket4", "#bracket5", "#bracket6", "#bracket7", "#bracket8",
    "#bracket9", "#bracket10", "#bracket11", "#bracket12", "#bracket13", "#bracket14", "#bracket15", "#bracket16"];

    var len = items.length;

    for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
        console.log(len);
        $(items[i]).html( i + ". " + dataTeamsData + items[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Possibly because the solution to finding a number one greater than some other number is to add one to it?

Comment: Hmm. Not that simple as the threat shows.

Comment: What threat? It's not simple to write `(i+1)`?

Answer (score 1):

In your loop, do this:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
    console.log(len);
    var itemNum = i + 1;
    $(items[i]).html( itemNum + ". " + dataTeamsData + items[i]);
}
```

itemNum will start at 1, while the item from the array will still be fetched by the index value i which starts at 0.

Alternatively, instead of this:

```
<div>1. item0</div>
<div>2. item1</div>
<div>3. item2</div>
...
```

Use an ordered list element with list items:

```
<ol>
    <li>item0</li>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    ...
</ol>
```

Then you don't have to worry about the number as it will be generated automatically.

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly. Why can't the +1 be in the the for loop though? I don't understand why var itemNum = i + 1; is needed in the code block.

Comment: Got it. My divs are unordered. This for a brackets winning page. The numbers are player #'s. Thanks.

Comment: itemNum is the count as opposed to i which is the item's index value. You can define itemNum outside of the array, but you use it in the loop so it's ok to define it there. Does that make sense?

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks!